# Is it possible to use only one resolution with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know if it's possible so that's why i'm starting this question.

Is it possible to only use one resolution(Medium desktop) with Bootstrap?

I'm asking this because the design i have it's designed for Medium desktop (970px wide). I want to use this design meanwhile i don't do the design for the other resolutions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with the [responsive utilities CSS classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities). You can use the `.hidden-*` classes to hide parts of your design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one type of class (col-md-*) http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic.